# C++ : concatenate char to a string?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to decale each character in the string that I give as argument by a number , so a +4 = e and so on... 
but somehow this function assigns only the last character of the string to my string test, and returning only last char at the end of the function without decalation... why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


string code(string, int ) ;

int main() {


int decalage(3);
string worth = "Hello worldas";
string result;

result += code(worth,decalage);
cout << "Resultat :" << result <<endl;

return 0;

}

string code(string worth, int decalage) {
string test;
char bst;
for (char wort : worth) {

    if (wort <= 90 && wort>= 65) {

        bst = (wort + decalage);

        if (bst > 90) {
        bst = (bst -90 +64);
        test += bst;                
        }   
        else { 
            test+=bst;
            }
        }
    else if (wort >= 97 && wort<=122) {
        bst  = (wort + decalage);

        if (bst > 122) {
        bst = (char)((int)bst -122 + 96);
        test += bst;        
        }
        else {
            test +=bst;
        }
        }
    else {
    test +=wort;
    }

}
return test;
}
```

Comment: I see no C code here. Why is this tagged C?

Comment: sorry I dont know the big differences between C and C++ yet..

Comment: @userXXX Then you should at least decide which language you're writing in. C has no classes and no `string`...

Comment: `(int)wort <= 90` There's no need for casting.

Comment: ok I tagged it C++ now... any idea why this does not work?

Comment: ok I found it out myself thx all..

Comment: Btw [here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cbca32bda4791c0) a version of your original code without all that casting and the numeric constants.

Answer (score 2):

You should move the two lines `test += bst;` outside of your if-branch. Like this:

```
std::string code(std::string worth, int decalage) {
  std::string test ="";
  for (char wort : worth) {
    if ((int)wort <= 90 && int(wort)>= 65) {
      char bst = (char)((int)wort + decalage);
      if ((int)bst > 90) {
        bst += (char)((int)bst -90 +64);
      }
      test += bst;
    }else if ((int)wort >= 97 && (int)wort<=122) {
      char bst  = (char)((int)wort + decalage);
      if ((int)bst > 122) {
        bst = (char)((int)bst -122 + 96);
      }
      test += bst;
    }else{
      test +=wort;
    }
  }
  return test;
}
```

Otherwise it will never be executed.

Comment: thx I figured it out now ;)